# Jupyter-lab doesn't see installed packages

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've created a virtual env and installed needed libraries, but when I try to import them in Jupter-lab I get an error "ModuleNotFoundError".

I am using 'venv' as a kernel, and when I run !pip list command in jupyter notebook it is showing me that library.

Comment: You don't want to be using an exclamation point with `pip` and `conda`. There are magics to insure they are acting the environment that is underlying the active kernel. So run `%pip install <package_needed>` inside your notebook cell. Let it complete and then restart the kernel. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) on why to avoid use of exclamation point with `pip` and `conda`. See ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands you can use from inside notebooks for most installs in modern Jupyter. There's a lot of outdated advice out there.